# Cloud Run, is the default url permanent?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-run

I'm currently experiencing an error with handshaking when communicating with the Cloud Run server in the Flutter Client.

```
Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake
```

I saw almost 100 answers, and they all about allowed the bad request of flutter http, and also included attributes related to allowing insecure http in the info.plist in ios. And I did every single one and it doesn't work. I just want to give up Cloud Run's custom domain.

So anyway! my question is ..

If the default url is permanent, is it okay to just use the rest api here?

```
https://<cloud-run-service-default-url>/v1/api..
```

Comment: Yes it's permanent

Comment: Can you have a look at my last comment to the answer?